NSLayoutConstraint crash and Height constraint is the cause
I am upgrading an old Xamarin.iOS app to the more modern .net MAUI.
Somehow a view working previously, now crash because of some conflict in the constraints I apply programmatically (no xib file)
Here my code
//"this" is the superview which is big as the screen. I already add the constraints to achieve that
ContainerAlert = new UIView
{
     TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
};
Add (ContainerAlert);
ContainerAlert.BackgroundColor = Colors.BACKGROUND;
AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create (this, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ContainerAlert, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0));
AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ContainerAlert, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0));
AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create (ContainerAlert, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 0.75f, 0));

//more code, add Title UIView and a UIButton

//calculate the visibile height of the table
float heightTable;
if(lingueToShow.Count > 7) {
    heightTable = HEIGHT_TABLE;
} else {
    heightTable = lingueToShow.Count * CellaLingua.HEIGHT_CELL;
}

var table = new UITableView(CGRect.Empty, UITableViewStyle.Plain) {
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
};

//HERE IS THE PROBLEM
var tableHeightConstraint = table.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(heightTable);
tableHeightConstraint.Active = true;


ContainerAlert.Add(table);
ContainerAlert.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(table, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ContainerAlert,    NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 0));
ContainerAlert.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(ContainerAlert, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, table, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, 0));
ContainerAlert.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(table, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, Title, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
ContainerAlert.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(table, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ContainerAlert, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));

My objective is to create a a view (ContainerAlert) which is centered in the screen and is big as its content.
As I said this works in a previous version of Xamarin, but now it crash.
Do you have some idea why?

Does it throw any exception?

Hi, no. It just crash. Both simulator and real device has this behavior. I enabled full debug symbol and disable the linker, but it print no log.

Is there any useful application output and  which line caused the crash?

No, no output. I infer that is this line by test:
var tableHeightConstraint = table.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(heightTable); tableHeightConstraint.Active = true;

Not sure if it helps, Auto Layout constraint crashes due to anchor....
